# react-native-intercom event listeners(such as WINDOW_DID_HIDE, WINDOW_DID_SHOW) not working on android

Tags: react-native, intercom

I have a problem for closing/canceling displayed intercom messenger in android. When I click the close(X) button, it does nothing.

I reliazed that `WINDOW_DID_HIDE`, `WINDOW_DID_SHOW` listeners does not work in **android**.

`"react-native": "0.65.1"`,
`"react-native-intercom": "^21.1.1"`

versions are used

`io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:10.4.0` used for android

and android/build.gradle **buildscript**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be the wrong with it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with the official react-native package [@intercom/intercom-react-native](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-react-native)